# Understanding the input_shape of LSTM model

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

I divided my database in 40 rolling windows so I have a dataframe with shape `(2000000, 132)`. Let's concentrate in the first window: it has 50k rows and the 132 columns so its shape is `(50000, 132)`. I want to use all of this to predict the value of a label in the following window but I don't know what values are needed in the `input_shape`. I put `input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))` because I think in each iteration I have `X_train.shape[1] = 132` columns and 1 timestep but I'm not sure. (I do each iteration with a `for` loop from 1 to 41)

The model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
```

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_24 (LSTM)              (None, 132, 50)           10400     
                                                                 
 lstm_25 (LSTM)              (None, 50)                20200     
                                                                 
 dense_11 (Dense)            (None, 1)                 51        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 30,651
Trainable params: 30,651
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LSTM, the input_shape is `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`.

First, you need to convert `X_train` to a 3D tensor. Each 50000x132 matrix will be a sample. So, `X_train` will be `(n_samples, 50000, 132)`.

Now, you can set the input shape to `(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])`.